# ruby script for pianobar to retrieve lyrics

Tags: python, ruby, shell

I am using the following Ruby script to send "now playing song info" of pianobar to the mac notification centre. What I'm trying to do is to get the song info like artist from the same ruby script and save it as a shell script file (.sh). I can run this script whenever I want to see the lyrics of now playing song via glyr.

```
trigger = ARGV.shift

if trigger == 'songstart'
songinfo = {}
STDIN.each_line { |line| songinfo.store(*line.chomp.split('=', 2))}

`/usr/bin/terminal-notifier -message "Artist: #{songinfo['artist']}\nAlbum: #    {songinfo['album']}" -title "#{songinfo['title']}"`
end
```

Output that need as a file is

```
  glyrc lyrics -a "Foster The People" -b "Torches"
```

I'm trying to use the variables #{songinfo['artist']} here. I added a new line before "end" as below

```
 `echo "glyrc lyrics -a "#{songinfo['artist']}" -b "#{songinfo['album']}""> test.txt`
```

this does the job but I get error "syntax error near unexpected token `(' " whenever the parentheses () appear on the album name, so this fails. So I went on using ruby method to create file using this

```
 File.write('test2.txt', 'glyrc lyrics')
```

The above simple script without any variables doesn't work at all when placed before the "end" though it works when I run it alone.

Comment: Please clarify what error you're getting whenever parentheses appear in the album name and when you get it. Also, please explain what you mean by "doesn't work" and "works" relative to `File.write(...)`.

Comment: if parentheses present then I get the syntax error near unexpected token `(' which is already known to occur with echo. With File.write I don't get any out put. Also updated my question.